# Exception assembling embedded component 'exceptiondisplay'

Tags: java, tapestry

I'm using tapestry5,maven,spring3.0.6.RELEASE and hibernate in my project and 
I'm stuck with this exception(the only possible solution I've found on Google was to replace openjdk implementation of java for the project with java-6-sun,but no luck,I still get the same error).

Here's the stack trace:

```
14-12-2011 12:57:42:333 11518 ERROR org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry  - Exception  assembling embedded component 'exceptiondisplay' (of type   org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.ExceptionDisplay, within core/ExceptionReport):  Could not convert 'stack' into a component parameter binding: Exception generating conduit  for expression 'stack': java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError
14-12-2011 12:57:42:333 11518 ERROR org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry  - Operations  trace:
14-12-2011 12:57:42:333 11518 ERROR org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry  - [ 1] Constructing instance of page class org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.pages.ExceptionReport
14-12-2011 12:57:42:334 11519 ERROR org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry  - [ 2] Assembling root component for page core/ExceptionReport
14-12-2011 12:57:42:334 11519 ERROR org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry  - [ 3] Assembling component core/ExceptionReport:exceptiondisplay (org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.ExceptionDisplay)
2011-12-14 12:57:42.334:WARN::/projektni/
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception assembling root component of page core/ExceptionReport: Exception assembling embedded component 'exceptiondisplay' (of type org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.ExceptionDisplay, within core/ExceptionReport): Could not convert 'stack' into a component parameter binding: Exception generating conduit for expression 'stack': java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.ComponentAssemblerImpl.performAssembleRootComponent(ComponentAssemblerImpl.java:135)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.ComponentAssemblerImpl.access$000(ComponentAssemblerImpl.java:44)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.ComponentAssemblerImpl$1.invoke(ComponentAssemblerImpl.java:92)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.ComponentAssemblerImpl$1.invoke(ComponentAssemblerImpl.java:89)
at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:65)
at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:68)
at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1082)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.ComponentAssemblerImpl.assembleRootComponent(ComponentAssemblerImpl.java:87)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.PageLoaderImpl$3.invoke(PageLoaderImpl.java:213)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.PageLoaderImpl$3.invoke(PageLoaderImpl.java:206)
at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:65)
at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:68)
at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1082)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.pageload.PageLoaderImpl.loadPage(PageLoaderImpl.java:205)
at $PageLoader_2e479c51ecc.loadPage(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageSourceImpl.getPage(PageSourceImpl.java:87)
at $PageSource_2e479c51ecb.getPage(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.NonPoolingRequestPageCacheImpl.get(NonPoolingRequestPageCacheImpl.java:83)
at $RequestPageCache_2e479c51eca.get(Unknown Source)
at $RequestPageCache_2e479c51ec4.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.handleRequestException(DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.java:77)
at $RequestExceptionHandler_2e479c51ea1.handleRequestException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestErrorFilter.service(RequestErrorFilter.java:42)
at $RequestHandler_2e479c51ea4.service(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$3.service(TapestryModule.java:1055)
at $RequestHandler_2e479c51ea4.service(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:1045)
at $RequestHandler_2e479c51ea4.service(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:90)
at $RequestHandler_2e479c51ea4.service(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:105)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:95)
at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withRead(ConcurrentBarrier.java:85)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter.service(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:119)
at $RequestHandler_2e479c51ea4.service(Unknown Source)
at $RequestHandler_2e479c51e97.service(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$HttpServletRequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:385)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.gzip.GZipFilter.service(GZipFilter.java:53)
at $HttpServletRequestHandler_2e479c51e99.service(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
at $HttpServletRequestFilter_2e479c51e96.service(Unknown Source)
at $HttpServletRequestHandler_2e479c51e99.service(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$1.service(TapestryModule.java:1005)
at $HttpServletRequestHandler_2e479c51e99.service(Unknown Source)
at $HttpServletRequestHandler_2e479c51e94.service(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:147)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
127.0.0.1 -  -  [14/Dec/2011:11:57:39 +0000] "GET /projektni/ HTTP/1.1" 500 83736 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using Tapestry 5.3.0 and Jetty 6.1.26. Tapestry 5.3.0 is an Alpha release.

Use version 5.3 instead, which is the final release.